# Dask keeps failing with killed worker exception while running TPOT

Tags: kubernetes, dask, dask-distributed, tpot

Im running [tpot](https://github.com/EpistasisLab/tpot) with dask running on kubernetes cluster on gcp, the cluster is 24 cores 120 gb memory with 4 nodes of kubernetes, my kubernetes yaml is

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
name: daskd-scheduler
labels:
app: daskd
role: scheduler
spec:
ports:
- port: 8786
  targetPort: 8786
  name: scheduler
- port: 8787
  targetPort: 8787
  name: bokeh
- port: 9786
  targetPort: 9786
  name: http
- port: 8888
  targetPort: 8888
  name: jupyter
selector:
  app: daskd
  role: scheduler

 type: LoadBalancer
 --- 
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
 name: daskd-scheduler
spec:
 replicas: 1
 template:
  metadata:
  labels:
    app: daskd
    role: scheduler
spec:
  containers:
  - name: scheduler
    image: uyogesh/daskml-tpot-gcpfs  # CHANGE THIS TO BE YOUR DOCKER HUB IMAGE
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: ["/opt/conda/bin/dask-scheduler"]
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 1
        memory: 20000Mi # set aside some extra resources for the scheduler
    ports:
     - containerPort: 8786
     ---
     apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
     kind: Deployment
     metadata:
       name: daskd-worker
     spec:
       replicas: 3
       template:
      metadata:
        labels:
        app: daskd
        role: worker
    spec:
  containers:
  - name: worker
    image: uyogesh/daskml-tpot-gcpfs  # CHANGE THIS TO BE YOUR DOCKER HUB IMAGE
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    command: [
      "/bin/bash",
      "-cx",
      "env && /opt/conda/bin/dask-worker $DASKD_SCHEDULER_SERVICE_HOST:$DASKD_SCHEDULER_SERVICE_PORT_SCHEDULER --nthreads 8 --nprocs 1 --memory-limit 5e9",
    ]
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 2
        memory: 20000Mi
```

My data is 4 million rows and 77 columns, whenever i run fit on the tpot classifier, it runs on the dask cluster for a while then it crashes, the output log looks like

```
KilledWorker:
("('gradientboostingclassifier-fit-1c9d29ce92072868462946c12335e5dd',
0, 4)", 'tcp://10.8.1.14:35499')
```

I tried increasing threads per worker as suggested by the dask distributed docs, yet the problem persists.
Some observations i have made are:

- It'll take longer time to crash if n_jobs is less (for n_jobs=4, it
  ran for 20 mins before crashing) where as crashes instantly for
  n_jobs=-1.
- It'll actually start working and get optimized model for fewer data,
  with 10000 data it works fine.

So my question is, what changes and modifications do i need to make this work, I guess its doable as ive heard dask is capable of handling even bigger data than mine.

Comment: I often find that a `KilledWorker` error is the result of running our of RAM on the workers. If you are able I would watch the memory usage of your workers as you run the calculation.

Answer (score 3):

Best practices described on Dask`s [official](https://kubernetes.dask.org/en/latest/#best-practices) documentation page say:

> Kubernetes resource limits and requests should match the
>   --memory-limit and --nthreads parameters given to the dask-worker command. Otherwise your workers may get killed by Kubernetes as they
>   pack into the same node and overwhelm that nodes’ available memory,
>   leading to **KilledWorker** errors.

In your case these configuration parameters` values don`t match from what I can see:

Kubernetes` Container limit **20** GB vs. dask-worker command limit **5** GB